# Public Variable accessed from separate Activity Crash Android

Tags: android, variables, public

I have a public variable set in my Main Activity that declares the App as the free version or paid (boolean).

I am receiving a lot of crash errors (null pointer exceptions) when it is accessed from a separate activity.  I can't reproduce this error on test devices so I can only assume that Android loses the Main Activity Variable when it is low on memory?

Typically this happens when my users navigate to the browser to download a file and then navigate back to my App.

Should I be setting a variable local to the Activity so it no longer references a separate Activity?  Or is there a way to keep that variable in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some sort of persistent storage, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) seem like a good option for the task at hand.